# Session cookie cleared when open new window with webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Webdriver, Internet Explorer 7 and Windows Vista.
When I click on a link that opens a new window through a JavaScript function using window.open(url), the window opens but instead of showing the intended screen it shows the login page since the session cookie has been cleared.

Is there any way of keeping that cookie allowing me to avoid to login anytime I open a window this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, both with IE6 (don't ask) and Firefox drivers. The odd thing is it doesn't always occur consistently across different machines.

Comment: Here's a similar issue description on google code: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1486&q=cookie&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: I have the same issue and I had the protected mode activated. I am trying to test it deactivating it but my app does not work on unprotected mode. have you managed to fix it @user233323 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, and to fix it I simply changed to protected mode (IE only):

[image]

Maybe this will work for you too?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this and to fix it I simply changed to NON-protected mode, unchecking it for the 4 zones (IE only):

[image: You have to uncheck the protected mode on the 4 zones]

Maybe this will work for you too?
Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884810/getting-all-the-cookies-set-in-all-iframes-using-selenium-internetexplorerdriver/33374026#33374026)

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
```

Comment: This is the opposite answer to the one asked.