# Getting all the cookies set in all iframes using Selenium InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, selenium

This is my problem :

I use the Selenium InternetExplorer Driver to open a new browser window with a button click:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnOpen"));
element.sendKeys("\n");
```

The new browser window opens and in one of the frames in this window an auto-submit form sets a number of cookies.

First I change focus to the new window:

```
driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
```

Then I change focus to the frame that had the new cookies set via the auto-submit form

```
driver.switchTo().frame("fm_MainApp");
```

now when I iterate through all the cookies in the driver:

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

the driver does not show the cookies that was set with the auto-submit form, yet I can clearly see that the cookies have been set in IE using httpAnalyzer.

The cookies were also set from the local domain and not a third party.

So I can see the cookies in IE but the driver can not see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its problem with IE Driver, I think, especially with IEDriverServer, it can't work properly with IE cookies.
Here is the [defect in selenium issues.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1227&q=ie%20cookies&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: As result can say that the main problem with IE )). It doesn't share cookie with js, but in request panel can see them submitted

Answer (score 1):

Until the defect is solved, you can solve it removing "Protected mode" from all the zones. So:

- Tools > Internet Options.
- Security Tab. For each zone:

  - Uncheck the "Enable Protected Mode"